# Python blocking recv returns less data than asked for

Tags: python, recv

I have an echo server in C and a test client in Python. The server has a limited read buffer, eg 16bytes. When a client send more than 16 bytes, it will first read 16, write back to client and then read again.

I tested the server with `telnet`, and I got back the same string as my input, even it's longer than 16 bytes. However this Python client does not work.

```
//data is initialized to be 20 bytes data
Len = 20
sock.setblocking(1)
sock.send(data)
recvdata = sock.recv(Len)
if(recvdata != data):
    print recvdata.encode('hex')
    print Len
    print data.encode('hex')
```

This client only receive the first 16 bytes that server writes back. The server log does show two writes (16 + 4). Python output looks like this

```
1234567890123456 //recvdata
20
12345678901234567890 //sent data
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, **How come a blocking `recv()` returns less data than it is asked for?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The length you give to `recv` is a maximum, not a target.  There's no guarantee that `recv` will wait for `Len` bytes to be received - it can return as soon as it's read any data at all.

The man page for `recv` says: *The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.*

If you need to read a given number of bytes, you need to call `recv` in a loop and concatenate the returned packets until you have read enough.

Comment: I think the man page is for unix syscall. Is it the same for python `recv()`?

Comment: In general, python library functions with unix-y names are about as thin wrappers as is possible while still allowing platform-independent behaviour.